# Depoly project to local file server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I´m having a problem depolying a project to our file server. 
So, what I want to do is, when I push my project to the bitbucket server, the project should also be on an file-server automatically.

I tried creating a bare repo on our file-server, but when I push with `push production master`  I'm always getting `remote: fatal: not a git repository`.

Is there some easier way to handle this?

Comment: `git remote show production` please.

Comment: You are my hero man, i was in the wrong directory. Thanks!